# Is the Bytecoin proposed scheme to scan numerous addresses faster interesting for Monero?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, scalability, address, bytecoin

What was the technical scheme proposed by Bytecoin to scan a set of addresses faster, for instance for merchants? Was it discussed for Monero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bytecoin's scheme is to create addresses which differ in their spend key, but not in their view key. In that way, they are able to scan incoming transactions once, using the shared view key, while being able to distinguish the provenance (assuming they assign one such key per possible sender).

I like this system, as it's pretty simple, very scalable, and even decreases the space needed on the blockchain due to not needing a payment id.

I do not think it was discussed for Monero, though moneromooo has said to like that scheme.

It is pertinent to note that these different addresses are still half identical, and thus two such addresses can be trivially known to be the same owner.

Comment: I think they were called "aggregate addresses" or similar. To be usable, they only must be implemented. :) (they are invisible protocol-wise; it's completely a wallet-side change)

Answer (score 3):

> It is pertinent to note that these different addresses are still half identical, and thus two such addresses can be trivially known to be the same owner.

Onchain you would not be able to group these addresses together, but indeed, offchain you would be able to see it. The reason XMR will get subaddresses is to avoid offchain grouping. You'll be able to create a new subaddress for every service you use.